# Move draggable objects to top of the screen or Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have draggable objects inside of a div. I'm trying to figure out how to allow a user to click a button and move the objects to an exact point on the screen (Even if they've dragged the object to a new location)

Any way to animate an object to the top of the screen regardless of where the object starts? (See working JSFiddle) Thanks!

I've been trying the code below but I cannot get it to work correctly.

```
var json = [

           {'x' : '200' , 'y' : '200'},

            ];


    function initPage() {
        $.each(json, function() {
            $("#point").animate({
                left: this.x,
                top: this.y
            },
            "linear");
        });
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unppstma/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another function to the onclick event on your button, with something like this:

```
function moveToTop(){
  $('#draggable1, #draggable2').animate({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top" : "0"
  })
}
```

Comment: As I wanted to see it in action, here is a working version of the same jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unppstma/18/
Probably it can be useful for somebody else.