# Reactjs: How to move dialog to top of the screen on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dialog, draggable

When I clicked over a draggable dialog, I want to move to the top of the screen.

I have tried with `scrollTo(0, 0)`, but this seems to not doing anything over my dialog box. Any help over it how can I able to move this dialog box.

Many Thanks in advance.
I am following this [Move draggable objects to top of the screen or Div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593362/move-draggable-objects-to-top-of-the-screen-or-div) example but need this to be with on click.

```
    class Homepage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          Pending:[],
          cancelled:[],
        }
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.myRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(!prevProps.isModerator){
          if(prevProps.Permission === Permission && 
              this.props.Permission === Requested){
          }
        }
      }
    
      render() {
        const {allowRequest, classes} = this.props;
        const { Pending} = this.state;
        return (
            <>
              {Pending.map((user, index) => {
                return <Draggable bounds="parent" key={user.id} ref={this.myRef}>
                  <div className={classes["share-request-content"]} >
                    <Paper className="alert-container" square={true}>
                      <DialogTitle id="alert-title">
                        {/* Title here */}
                      </DialogTitle>
                      <DialogContent>
                      {/* Content here */}
                      </DialogContent>
                      <DialogActions className="dialog-action">
                        <Button autoFocus color="primary" onClick={() => allowRequest(user.id)}>
                          "Allow"
                        </Button>
                      </DialogActions>
                    </Paper>
                  </div>
                </Draggable>
              })
              }
            </>
        )
      }
    }
    
    Homepage.propTypes = {
      Permission: PropTypes.string,
      isModerator: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      Pending: PropTypes.array,
      cancelled: PropTypes.array,
    };
    
    export default withStyles(styles)(injectIntl(Homepage))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the position={{x:0, y:0}} property to manually control the position of the dialog.

You can find the references here: https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable

Comment: Hi Jassim thank you for your time. But I want to do this when I make a click over it. but this is about default position. Isn't it ?

Comment: No. Default position has different option for it defaultPosition={{x: 0, y: 0}}. Lookup the part of Controlled V/S UnControlled in the documentation for better clarity

Comment: Would you mind to suggest me how can i make this happen with onclick. There is no example I found here https://strml.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/0-showcase.html